# VSCode: How do I stop 'Clear Search Results' action from clearing out 'Files to exclude'?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This didn't use to happen before but now, when I hit the 'Clear Search Results' button, all fields in Search are cleared out. I want to retain the 'Files to exclude' input

Comment: It looks like there is no way to do that now, with the recent version of VS Code. You might want to vote on the issue reported to their Github Issues page: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68367

Comment: And see the referenced change that caused the new default behavior as well: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of the 'Clear Search Results' button has been recently changed, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/100024.

And the changes are in the Insiders' Build now.

The first click clears the search results and the query/replace terms and does not affect the `Files to Include/Exclude` fields.

The second click clears the `Files to Include/Exclude` fields.